# struggling with shell extension

Tags: macos, shell, netlogo

For a little bit of context, I am in the process of developing a serious game (~participatory simulation) with Netlogo using Hubnet. I'd like to dynamically link NetLogo with an external model so that players are able to:
1) run an external program (i.e. a model) from their hubnet client interface, specifying parameters as inputs, and
2) have access to simulation results (i.e. reading model outputs as external files).

I found that post:
https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/conversations/topics/8145

so I downloaded/installed the shell extensions with NetLogo 5.0.5 (Mac OsX 10.7.5) and started to play with it.

The good things, I am able to execute :

*observer>shell:cd "path"*

*observer>shell:pwd*

*observer>shell:exec "ls"* (and all commands that do not need input parameters such as *shell:exec "cal*", *shell:exec "df"*...).

Now the bad things...

1) I am consistently failing to launch any random application using these commands: 
*observer>shell:exec "Safari.app" 
or 
observer>shell:exec "Safari" (-->error)*

My working directory is correct and Safari (or other apps I am trying to launch) is actually present but NetLogo returns the following error:

***Extension exception: Cannot run program "Safari" (in directory "/Applications"): error=2, No such file or directory
error while observer running SHELL:EXEC
  called by Command Center***

2) I am also struggling to execute shell commands taking parameters (for instance, *shell:exec "open" "parameter 1" "parameter 2"* ...). I am unable to find the correct syntax so that NetLogo don't recognize the input parameters I'm trying to pass to the command.

I have a very limited experience in Unix and I am a relative beginner with NetLogo so I must be missing something somewhere.

If anybody could help me through this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Clément

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is OS X, you have to use `open` to open `.app` files. As you noted, you have to separate arguments to the program. So

`(shell:exec "open" "/Applications/Safari.app")`

should do what you want.

Here's an example of an actual executable with multiple arguments:

`(shell:exec "ls" "-l" "-t")`

Finally, note that `shell:exec` is a reporter. It returns the output of the program as a string.